# The experts in the field and the dictionary give the definition of words (such as Wisdom, etc). Which one is more precise?

Tags: meaning

Ok, the Philosopher defines "Wisdom" as the "the use of knowledge" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom) whereas the dictionary defines "Wisdom" as "the quality of having experience, knowledge, and good judgment; the quality of being wise" (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Awisdom)

So The experts in the field and the dictionary, which one give more precise the definition of the some special term

Comment: There are various definitions for "wisdom".  For example, Buddhists may define "wisdom" to be seeing the true nature of reality.  I think you need to consider why it matters who defines wisdom.  Perhaps you should consider the context and choose a definition best aligned for your context.

Comment: A dictionary is **descriptive**, not **proscriptive**.  This is the most famous thing written in the most famous introduction to an edition of the OED.

Comment: Which one do you think is more precise?  Do you think you must choose only one? Be glad you have multiple sources to help you not only clarify, but to see subtle nuances of meaning. Precision is an absolute good only in mathematics.

Comment: Dictionaries don't always agree, especially on how many senses a word has. Dictionaries never give all the information that is 'out there' (even OED does not include hundreds of thousands of the 1 000 000+ words claimed to be in the English language). Some specialist dictionaries will doubtless give more/different information about specialist usages in their registers than even OED. Experts certainly disagree on terminology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is imprecisely worded (_which_ dictionary?  who decides on who are the true experts?) and assumes that words are not polysemous (and especially that senses may not differ significantly across registers).

Comment: In any case, remember that precision has nothing to do with accuracy. You can come up with a very specific, precise definition of a word that has no relation to actual use of the word.

Comment: It's rare that a dictionary, even one as complete as OED, is able to describe all the nuances in the ways that words are used, as well as all the differences depending on context and perspective.

Comment: Wisdom is the ability to correctly pick between two apparently equivalent choices.

Comment: The Wikipedia article contains various definitions of 'wisdom'; it's a pity not to quote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different philosophers define wisdom differently, and the readers and/or hearers of each must understand that that philosopher’s definition is the proper one to guide interpretation of that philosopher’s statements involving this term. Dictionary definitions, by contrast, tend to be less precise, and multiple, so as to cover the range of what a vast community of users generally seem mean by the term. Whether you consider yourself a philosopher or not, you should offer your own more precise and narrow definition if and only if an ordinary dictionary would not provide sufficient guidance for your audience, regarding the way you intend to use the term. (If an ordinary dictionary *does* provide sufficient guidance, you needn’t and generally shouldn’t quote it in any academic paper.)

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatically, wisdom implies the "quality" of the knowledge and experience and the resulting "good judgment"--acquisition of both does not impy "wisdom."